# Wordpress Custom post query for slider

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, custom-post-type

I'm trying to convert a HTML slider into wordpress by custom post. Here is the HTML Markup for the slider

`<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide_item">
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide_item">
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide_item">
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
    </div>
</div>`

I converted many slider using custom post before but this sliders markup is something complex to me and can't understand How to convert this slider into wordpress.

[Please see this screenshot](http://prntscr.com/3va5qh),  that will be easy to understand.

Normally I use the below query to convert slider. Please help me someone by giving me the custom post query code to convert the above slider. Advance Thanks! to all.

```
    `<?php if(!is_paged()) { ?>
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>  
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="slide_item">
        <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if(!is_paged()) { ?>
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider', 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$count=1;
?>

<div class="slider">  
<div class="slide_item">
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="child_item_of_every_slide">Child Slide Items with different Content</div>
<?php
if($count%4==1&&$count>1){
    echo '</div><div class="slide_item">';
    }
    $count++;
 ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Glad i could help.
You could upvote the answer if that worked.